# ffmpeg - whatsapp: video format not supported

Tags: ffmpeg, whatsapp

I have two videos (.mp4) files. One uploads to whatsapp and another does not.

Using ffmpeg I checked their properties:

a) Properties of video which uploads:

```
  Duration: 00:00:56.45, start: 0.148000, bitrate: 1404 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1080x1080, 1359 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (HE-AACv2) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 47 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
At least one output file must be specified
```

b) video which does not upload to whatsapp (because its says format not supported)

```
  Duration: 00:00:56.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 543 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 1080x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 464 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 23.98 tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([255][0][0][0] / 0x00FF), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 56 kb/s
```

The difference in video I noticed:

`(avc1 / 0x31637661)`  vs `(H264 / 0x34363248)`

`1359 kb/s` vs `464 kb/s`

`90k tbn` vs `23.98 tbn`

What can be the reason?

Also the second video is not being played in Android.

The link for the video is  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4UM6vTHw4pyMExQQ1lxZGp0N2c

Comment: Are you generating the 2nd video using ffmpeg?

Comment: The same question was asked [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/564kyc/ffmpeg_whatsapp_video_format_not_supported/?st=ivjxdi0v&sh=848ce7eb) and there's a solution there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2023-01-22 I used the most upvoted answer format and it worked for video, but audio was not working on iPhones. Here's what worked for me:

```
ffmpeg -i broken.mp4 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -ac 2 working.mp4
```

I had to add `-ac 2` because the audio format I had wasn't seen as stereo by iOS.

Answer (score 122):

There are some options for a better compatibility:

`ffmpeg -i broken.mp4 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -pix_fmt yuv420p working.mp4`

With `-profile:v baseline -level 3.0` you make the file more compatible with most older players, including WhatsApp ;). Although, this disables some advanced features.

`-pix_fmt yuv420p` is necessary to compile to baseline (YUV planar color space with 4:2:0 chroma subsampling).

Also, you can adjust other options as bitrate, framerate, audio, etc.

Source: [H.264 docs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)

Comment: in my case the problem came out to be the pix_fmt which was not yuv420p

Comment: Nice thanks, worked like a charm! If only Kazam could use these settings right away it would make it easier to screencap and share.

Comment: Setting `-pix_fmt yuv420p` is needed when converting from GIF.

Comment: Seriously, this worked great, but how, how can you possibly know this massive command line?? 

Comment: @CaioMar I really don't remember how did I get it. I think by researching in ffmpeg H264 documentation and "try and failure". It's all about "compatibility"... and h264 encoding has options for that .

Comment: So frustrating that this no longer works :(

Comment: @JamieHutber I still use this command. Not only that, I think that WhatsApp Web is more flexible than before, that it accept more formats. What's your ffmpeg version?

Comment: Interesting. I wonder indeed then. `ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright` I have the same script, it has not changed. But now they do not work. Let me look to upgrade ffmpeg

Comment: Would you believe it... whatsapp just released an update that fixed this!!! Within the last 10mins :D Now the files are working

Answer (score 12):

I tried all previous commands and I got some errors. I was able to encode my video using this command and here is the explanation and why I set it up like this for a better compatibility:

```bash
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 \
 -vf "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2" -vb 1024k \
 -acodec aac -ar 44100 -ac 2\
 -minrate 1024k -maxrate 1024k -bufsize 1024k \
 -movflags +faststart \
 output.mp4
```

- If your input contains **AAC audio** you can [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) instead of re-encoding by changing `-acodec aac -ar 44100 -ac 2` to `-acodec copy` to preserve the audio quality.

| option | explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `-vcodec libx264` | Chooses video encoder *libx264* |
| `-pix_fmt yuv420p` | Ensures YUV 4:2:0 chroma subsampling for compatibility |
| `-profile:v baseline` | Set the encoding profile to [**baseline**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Video_Coding#Profiles). Used primarily for low-cost applications that require additional data loss robustness |
| `-level 3.0` | Set the operating point level to [**3.0**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Video_Coding#Levels) which is necessary to have compatibility with WhatsApp |
| `-vf "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2"` | If you get not divisible by 2 error see |
| `-acodec aac` | Chooses audio encoder *aac* |
| `-minrate 1024k` | set min bitrate tolerance to 1024k (in bits/s). It is of little use elsewise |
| `-maxrate 1024k` | set max bitrate tolerance to 1024k (in bits/s). Requires bufsize to be set |
| `-bufsize 1024k` | set rate-control buffer size to 1024k (in bits) |
| `-movflags +faststart` | enables fast start for streaming |

### Note about faststart

Normally, a MP4 file has all its **metadata** packets stored at the end of the file, in data units named **atoms**. The `mdat` atom is located before the `moov` atom. If the file is created by adding the `-movflags faststart`, the `moov` atom is moved at the beginning of the MP4 file. By using this option, the `moov` atom is located before the `mdat` atom. This allows video playback to begin before the file has been completely downloaded.

Comment: Just tried it and works, after trying a different version down here that apparently stopped working now. April 2022.

Comment: Does the +faststart benefit Whatsapp ?
Also, can you use -movflags with .mp4 and not just .mov ?

Comment: None worked from "whatsapp web". Had to move file to the phone to upload from app and it works now

Answer (score 8):

Copied from https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/564kyc/ffmpeg_whatsapp_video_format_not_supported/?st=ivjxdi0v&sh=848ce7eb

```
ffmpeg -i brokenvideo.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac fixedvideo.mp4
```

Also had to apply this fix: [FFMPEG (libx264) "height not divisible by 2"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847674/ffmpeg-libx264-height-not-divisible-by-2)

Comment: This command will re-encode the video and audio. I bet this is just a matter of the video tag. Try `ffmpeg -i broken.mp4 -c copy -vtag avc1 fixed.mp4`

Answer (score 7):

This is worked for me in 2020

```
ffmpeg -i broken.mp4 -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -level 3.0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -brand mp42 fixed.mp4
```

Comment: same (and the others didn't)

Comment: I don't find `-brand mp42` as an option of ffmpeg or H264 encoding. Maybe this is from MP4Box [(here)](https://ffmpeg-user.ffmpeg.narkive.com/2ZHSzr9f/remux-to-a-brand-mp42-mp4-file). If you want to set fourcc as `mp42` with ffmpeg, then you shoud use `-tag:v mp42`.

Comment: It is still working

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me, in 2022

Answer (score 0):

Copying [@teocci's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71865582/2432830) for powershell:

```
ffmpeg -i 'input.mp4' `
-c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p `
-vf "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2" -vb 1024k `
-acodec aac -ar 44100 -ac 2 `
-minrate 1024k -maxrate 1024k -bufsize 1024k `
-movflags +faststart `
output.mp4
```

If you video already has aac:

```
ffmpeg -i 'input.mp4' `
-c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p `
-vf "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2" -vb 1024k `
-acodec copy `
-minrate 1024k -maxrate 1024k -bufsize 1024k `
-movflags +faststart `
output.mp4
```

Check out the original answer for mode details. Not allowed to comment so posting an answer instead