# PHP-FFMpeg Error while opening encoder for output stream

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use this PHP-FFMpeg library, but I'm keep getting errors like

```
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0
```

This is my PHP code

```
private function createTeaserVideos($fullVideoPath, $databasePath, $uploadPath) {
        $ffmpeg = FFMpeg::create([
            'ffmpeg.binaries' => '/usr/bin/ffmpeg',
            'ffprobe.binaries' => '/usr/bin/ffprobe',
            'timeout'          => 0,
        ]);

        $ffmpeg->getFFMpegDriver()->listen(new \Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Listeners\DebugListener());
        $ffmpeg->getFFMpegDriver()->on('debug', function ($message) {
            var_dump($message);
        });

        // Create teaser_video_thumb
        $videoNameThumb = $this->randomTimeString() . '-thumb.mp4';
        $video = $ffmpeg->open($fullVideoPath);
        $video
            ->filters()
            ->resize(new \FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(400, 280))
            ->synchronize();
        $video->save(new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('aac', 'libx264'), $uploadPath . $videoNameThumb);
    }
```

So what I'm trying to do here. User uploads his video and I'm trying to resize it and create one smaller video for the preview. The problem that I'm keep getting it is

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1' (length=46)
 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers' (length=54)
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 20160609' (length=72)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv' (length=1135)
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch' (length=49)
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --disable-avdevice --disable-avfilter --disable-avformat --disable-avresample --disable-postproc --disable-swscale --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libvo_aacenc --enable-libvo_amrwbenc' (length=1413)
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100' (length=48)
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100' (length=48)
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101' (length=48)
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100' (length=48)
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101' (length=48)
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0' (length=48)
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101' (length=48)
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101' (length=48)
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100' (length=48)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/vagrant/workspace/spot-scouting-adminpage/static/locations/MjY5MjI2Y2E0NDExOWNmZmQwN/teaser/f4095e9eeb364fe187bf1ed42eedc198.mp4':' (length=185)
  Metadata:' (length=19)
    major_brand     : mp42' (length=34)
    minor_version   : 0' (length=31)
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41' (length=39)
    creation_time   : 2019-01-04 12:46:43' (length=49)
  Duration: 00:00:08.41, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10261 kb/s' (length=69)
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 9982 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50 tbc (default)' (length=153)
    Metadata:' (length=21)
      creation_time   : 2019-01-04 12:46:43' (length=51)
      handler_name    : Alias Data Handler' (length=50)
      encoder         : AVC Coding' (length=42)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)' (length=109)
    Metadata:' (length=21)
      creation_time   : 2019-01-04 12:46:43' (length=51)
      handler_name    : Alias Data Handler' (length=50)
-async is forwarded to lavfi similarly to -af aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0.' (length=107)
[libx264 @ 0x136f620] height not divisible by 2 (400x225)' (length=65)
Output #0, mp4, to '/home/vagrant/workspace/spot-scouting-adminpage/static/locations/MjY5MjI2Y2E0NDExOWNmZmQwN/teaser/gY0RfV9c0y06592770015466174550YfY9-thumb.mp4':' (length=172)
  Metadata:' (length=19)
    major_brand     : mp42' (length=34)
    minor_version   : 0' (length=31)
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41' (length=39)
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264, none, q=2-31, 128 kb/s, 25 fps (default)' (length=83)
    Metadata:' (length=21)
      creation_time   : 2019-01-04 12:46:43' (length=51)
      handler_name    : Alias Data Handler' (length=50)
      start_time      : 0' (length=33)
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libx264' (length=53)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac, 0 channels, 128 kb/s (default)' (length=72)
    Metadata:' (length=21)
      creation_time   : 2019-01-04 12:46:43' (length=51)
      handler_name    : Alias Data Handler' (length=50)
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 aac' (length=49)
Stream mapping:' (length=23)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))' (length=63)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))' (length=60)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height' (length=127)
' (length=8)
```

I can't figure out what is the problem or how to solve it. Can someone please help me out? I'm using Ubuntu 16 and I have installed ffmpeg via apt-get install ffmpeg. 
If you need any additional infomations, please let me know and I will provide. Thank you

Comment: 1. Please show the actual `ffmpeg` command being executed by your script. 2. Your `ffmpeg` is ancient. [Download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) a build from the git master branch and try again. 3. Refer to [FFMPEG (libx264) “height not divisible by 2”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20847674/1109017).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was following. First i have reinstalled my ffmpeg with more latest version. 
I did a following

```
cd
wget https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/builds/ffmpeg-git-amd64-static.tar.xz
tar xvf ffmpeg-git-amd64-static.tar.xz
sudo mv ffmpeg-git-20190101-amd64-static/ffmpeg ffmpeg-git-20190101-amd64-static/ffprobe /usr/local/bin/
whereis ffmpeg
rm -f ffmpeg-git-amd64-static.tar.xz
```

Then I have changed the code, to look like following

```
private function createTeaserVideos($fullVideoPath, $databasePath, $uploadPath) {
    $ffmpeg = FFMpeg::create([
        'ffmpeg.binaries' => '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg',
        'ffprobe.binaries' => '/usr/local/bin/ffprobe',
        'timeout'          => 0,
    ]);

    // Create teaser_video_thumb
    $videoNameThumb = $this->randomTimeString() . '-thumb.mp4';
    $video = $ffmpeg->open($fullVideoPath);
    $video
        ->filters()
        ->resize(new \FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(THUMBNAIL_WIDTH, THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT))
        ->synchronize();

    $format = new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264();
    $format->setVideoCodec('libx264');
    $format->setAudioCodec('aac');
    $format->setAdditionalParameters( [ '-crf', '10'] );

    $video->save($format, $uploadPath . $videoNameThumb);

    return [
        'thumb' => $databasePath . $videoNameThumb,
    ];
}
```

Another problem that I had, was my new video height was not dividable by / 2. So it looks like, ffmpeg needs to have height which can be divided by 2.