# Ffmpeg change resolution h.264

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to add a option to ffmpeg command to change the video resolution to **5760x2880** with keeping the right aspect ratio so the video isn't distorted my current command is

```
 -i {INPUTFILE} -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 0 -r:v 30 -c:a copy {OUTPUTFILE}
```

Thank you

Comment: See [Resizing videos with ffmpeg to fit into static size](https://superuser.com/a/1136305/110524) or [FFMPEG (libx264) “height not divisible by 2”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29582287/1109017), depending on the method you want to use.

Comment: Thanks can you give me a example with my command I'm using where does that go

Comment: It's an output option, so anywhere between `{INPUTFILE}` and `{OUTPUTFILE}`.