# ffmpeg : width not divisible by 2 (when keep proportions)

Tags: ffmpeg

I try to reduce the dimensions of video:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -y -acodec aac -ac 2 -ab 160k -vcodec libx264 -vf "scale=-1:'min(720,ih)'" -f mp4 output.mp4
```

I got :

> width not divisible by 2 (405x720)

I tried with:

```
 -vf "scale=-1:'min(720,ceil(ih/2)*2)'"
```

Go the same because I need to keep width propotions

Any idea ?

I already read that without success:

[FFMPEG (libx264) "height not divisible by 2"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847674/ffmpeg-libx264-height-not-divisible-by-2)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
scale='bitand(oh*dar,65534)':'min(720,ih)'
```

This will rescale the width proportional to the output height and then reduce it an even value.

Comment: Can you please explain what `65534` is? My current command for scaling is `scale=999:trunc(ow/a/2)*2,overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2`

Comment: I have asked a question, can you please have a look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62955932/ffmpeg-width-not-divisible-by-2

Answer (score 3):

Use `"scale=-2:'min(720,ih)'"`

In general you can put -N to force it to be a multiple of N when keeping the aspect ratio, so if you were using a codec that required widths to be a multiple of 16, you could use -16 for the width.