# Convert image and audio in background to Video file in React Native

Tags: react-native, ffmpeg

I am trying to convert the images to video with audio in the background in React Native. I had used ffmpeg but I am not getting the expected result.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ffmpeg
Here is the code that I had tried!

```
RNFFmpeg.execute('-i http://192.168.43.4/ReactFirstProject/images/song.jpeg -i http://192.168.43.4/ReactFirstProject/screens/music/frog.wav -c:v mpeg4 output.mp4').then(result => (console.log("RESULT:",result)))
```

Can anyone suggest any other libraries for doing the same? Please help me out. I would be glad.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of suggesting another library I can give suggestions about your `ffmpeg` command:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i http://192.168.43.4/ReactFirstProject/images/song.jpeg -i http://192.168.43.4/ReactFirstProject/screens/music/frog.wav -vf format=yuv420p -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -movflags +faststart -shortest output.mp4
```

Some assumptions are being made here given the lack of info provided ("not getting the expected result" isn't very informative), and the log from the `ffmpeg` command would have been very helpful.

I'm guessing you don't actually want the old, legacy, outdated MPEG-4 Part 2  video format so I changed the encoder to libx264 to output H.264 video.

I'm also assuming that `song.jpeg` has even values for width and height. Otherwise, see one of the many answers in [FFmpeg: libx264 - height not divisible by 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20847674/1109017).

Comment: not getting expected result means I only get an output as 1 {rc: 1}

Comment: @ForamTrada I don't understand what that means.

Comment: sir , what to use now, as ffmpeg get deprecated...Please help sir

Answer (score 0):

Possible issues I faced with return code 1:

1. output directory doesnot exist --> make sure directory exist before using ffmpeg (e.g create directory by RNFS.mkdir with [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs), it will create dir if not exist and not return error if dir existed)
2. output file already existing --> Use -y flag to overwrite existing file or prevent using same filename for output file.

Checkout [FFmpeg Kit](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit). I was using ffmpegkit but not react-native-ffmpeg, which is superseded by FFmpegKit.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).