# FFMPEG YUV444 to YUV420

Tags: ffmpeg

Soo I need to use a video reader which onl accepts yuv420.
I have videos which are yuv444 and have very weird resolutions (they come from an algorith and they are videos manually created stacking frames)

Soo I tried the following

```
ffmpeg -i CJMOPvsinJE.mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p yuv420.mp4
```

But it seems that resolution have to be even.

```
[libx264 @ 0x556e02626660] width not divisible by 2 (241x1080)
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Sooo I solved it by cropping.

```
ffmpeg -i CJMOPvsinJE.mp4 -filter:v "crop=240:1080:1:0" -pix_fmt yuv420p yuv420.mp4
```

Buuut The fact is that I need to perform this operation for a bunch of videos.

**Is there a way to tell ffmpeg to crop to the nearest even resolution?** Namely, if resolution is odd just to remove 1 row/column.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29582287/) (not the accepted answer in the duplicate link).

Comment: @llogan Thank you it's just what i needed :)